# @onetoone and @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a one-to-one relation between a class, lets call it First, and another one lets call it second.

It wont allow me to do so if the class Second uses a @EmbeddedId as its primary key, how do i get around this?

Basically the structures are as follows:

```
@Entity
class First {
     private Integer id;
     private Second second;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="id",  referencedColumnName="parentId", nullable=true)        
     public Second getSecond() {return second;}
     ... snip irrelevant methods ...
}

@Entity
class Second{
     private Integer id;
     private Integer parentId;
     ... snip irrelevant methods ...
}
```

The above works fine, but if i change it to

```
@Entity
class Second{
     private MyCustomKey key;
     private Integer parentId;
     ... snip irrelevant methods ...
}
```

I get a "Broken mapping" error.

I fail to see the difference, since both ids are manually assigned? Both the working version with a integer id, and the embedded id.

Comment: You're trying to map Second class with non-key field. You have 'key' field as a Primary Key, but in JoinColumn annotation you use parentId (which is not a key at all) as a key to map OneToOne relationship.

Comment: But I map to parentId in the working example as well? Its not a key in that mapping either, but still works. The only difference between the two, is that the primary key(which is not used in the mapping at all) is changed into a composite key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, that works for me.

First entity

```
@Entity
public class Ent1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5580880562659281420L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setA(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private Integer a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="second",  referencedColumnName="parentId", nullable=true) 
    private Ent2 second;

    public void setSecond(Ent2 second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Second entity class (with composite PK)

```
@Entity
public class Ent2 implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1554968351865549494L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private Ent2Id id;

    public Ent2Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Ent2Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    Integer parentId;
}
```

And My custom key class

```
@Embeddable
public class Ent2Id implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3000940427471306899L;

    Integer eid1 = 0;
    Integer eid2 = 1;

    public Ent2Id() {

    }

    public Ent2Id(Integer a, Integer b) {
        eid1 = a;
        eid2 = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried you code and it works here as well, after revisiting my own code i came to a quite embarrasing discovery.. it was a method naming problem (as in they didnt match :|) thanks alot for the help :)